# Issue with Language-based Redirection on Homepage

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have a JavaScript code snippet that performs language-based redirection on my website. The code works fine on all pages except for the homepage. On the homepage, it adds "en/en" or "ar/ar" to the URL if the browser language is English or Arabic, respectively. I need assistance in resolving this issue.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  console.log("DOMContentLoaded event triggered");

  var excludedUrls = ["/customer-center", "/en/customer-center", "/ar/customer-center", "/make-payment", "/make-payment/1", "/make-payment/2", "/make-payment/3", "/make-payment/4", "/make-payment/5", "/make-payment/6", "/en/make-payment", "/en/make-payment/1", "/en/make-payment/2", "/en/make-payment/3", "/en/make-payment/4", "/en/make-payment/5", "/en/make-payment/6", "/ar/make-payment", "/ar/make-payment/1", "/ar/make-payment/2", "/ar/make-payment/3", "/ar/make-payment/4", "/ar/make-payment/5", "/ar/make-payment/6", "/cart", "/en/cart", "/ar/cart"]; // Exclude these URLs from redirection
  var storedLang = localStorage.getItem('lang');
  var userLang;
  
  if (storedLang) {
    userLang = storedLang;
  } else {
    userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage; 
    userLang = userLang.substr(0,2).toLowerCase();
    localStorage.setItem('lang', userLang);
  }
  
  console.log("Chosen language:", userLang);

  var currentUrl = window.location.href;
  var baseUrl = currentUrl.split("/")[0] + "//" + currentUrl.split("/")[2];
  var path = currentUrl.substring(baseUrl.length);

  // Check if the current path is in the list of excluded URLs
  if (!excludedUrls.includes(path)) {
    if (userLang === "tr") {
      if (path.includes("/en/") || path === "/en") {
        window.location.href = baseUrl + path.replace("/en", "/");
      } else if (path.includes("/ar/") || path === "/ar") {
        window.location.href = baseUrl + path.replace("/ar", "/");
      } 
    } else if (userLang === "en") {
      if (path.includes("/ar/")) {
        window.location.href = baseUrl + path.replace("/ar/", "/en/");
      } else if (!path.includes("/en/")) {
        if (path === "/ar" || path === "/") {
          window.location.href = baseUrl + "/en/";
        } else {
          window.location.href = baseUrl + "/en" + path;
        }
      }
    } else if (userLang === "ar") {
      if (path.includes("/en/")) {
        window.location.href = baseUrl + path.replace("/en/", "/ar/");
      } else if (!path.includes("/ar/")) {
        if (path === "/en" || path === "/") {
          window.location.href = baseUrl + "/ar/";
        } else {
          window.location.href = baseUrl + "/ar" + path;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

It seems that when the browser language is detected as English or Arabic on the homepage, the code adds an extra language segment to the URL, resulting in "en/en" or "ar/ar". However, this issue doesn't occur on other pages.

I would appreciate any guidance on how to fix this problem and ensure that the code works correctly on the homepage. Thank you!

I tried implementing a language-based redirection code on my website's homepage using the provided JavaScript snippet. I expected the code to correctly detect the browser language and redirect the user to the appropriate language version of the homepage (e.g., "/en" for English, "/ar" for Arabic). However, instead of redirecting to the correct language version, the code added an extra language segment to the URL, resulting in "en/en" or "ar/ar" on the homepage. This issue does not occur on other pages of the website. I would like to understand the cause of this problem and find a solution to ensure that the code functions correctly on the homepage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking for `/en/` in the path when it can be just `/en`.

You could use a regular expression to check for `/en` followed by another slash or the end of the string.

Replace `else if (!path.includes("/en/"))` with `else if (!/\/en(\/|$)/.test(path))`.

Comment: Thank You @Unmitigated ! The suggested modification using the regular expression \/en(\/|$) and \/ar(\/|$) effectively resolved the problem. Now, the code works perfectly, and the extra language segment is no longer added to the URL on the homepage. I am truly grateful for the prompt and helpful response. Your expertise and willingness to assist have been invaluable in solving this issue. Thank you all for your time and effort in providing a solution that works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  console.log("DOMContentLoaded event triggered");

  var excludedUrls = ["/customer-center", "/en/customer-center", "/ar/customer-center", "/make-payment", "/make-payment/1", "/make-payment/2", "/make-payment/3", "/make-payment/4", "/make-payment/5", "/make-payment/6", "/en/make-payment", "/en/make-payment/1", "/en/make-payment/2", "/en/make-payment/3", "/en/make-payment/4", "/en/make-payment/5", "/en/make-payment/6", "/ar/make-payment", "/ar/make-payment/1", "/ar/make-payment/2", "/ar/make-payment/3", "/ar/make-payment/4", "/ar/make-payment/5", "/ar/make-payment/6", "/cart", "/en/cart", "/ar/cart"]; 
  var storedLang = localStorage.getItem('lang');
  var userLang;
  
  if (storedLang) {
    userLang = storedLang;
  } else {
    userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage; 
    userLang = userLang.substr(0,2).toLowerCase();
    localStorage.setItem('lang', userLang);
  }
  
  console.log("Chosen language:", userLang);

  var currentUrl = window.location.href;
  var baseUrl = currentUrl.split("/")[0] + "//" + currentUrl.split("/")[2];
  var path = currentUrl.substring(baseUrl.length);

  if (!excludedUrls.includes(path)) {
    if (userLang === "tr") {
      if (path.includes("/en/") || path === "/en") {
        window.location.href = baseUrl + path.replace("/en", "/");
      } else if (path.includes("/ar/") || path === "/ar") {
        window.location.href = baseUrl + path.replace("/ar", "/");
      } 
    } else if (userLang === "en") {
      if (path.includes("/ar/")) {
        window.location.href = baseUrl + path.replace("/ar/", "/en/");
      } else if (!path.includes("/en/")) {
        if (path === "/ar" || path === "/") {
          window.location.href = baseUrl + "/en";
        } else {
          window.location.href = baseUrl + "/en" + path;
        }
      }
    } else if (userLang === "ar") {
      if (path.includes("/en/")) {
        window.location.href = baseUrl + path.replace("/en/", "/ar/");
      } else if (!path.includes("/ar/")) {
        if (path === "/en" || path === "/") {
          window.location.href = baseUrl + "/ar";
        } else {
          window.location.href = baseUrl + "/ar" + path;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The changes I made are within the "en" and "ar" sections of the logic. If the path equals "/", I simply add the language segment to baseUrl instead of baseUrl plus path. This will prevent the additional language segment from appearing in your URLs when the script is run on the homepage.